# Notify Fragment when LoaderManager starts loading

Tags: android, android-listview, android-fragments, android-loadermanager, asynctaskloader

I have **ListFragment** and **AsyncTaskLoader** which fetches data from internet. **ListFragment** is filled by **BaseAdapter**.

When data is loading, **BaseAdapter** fills the first row with spinning progress bar. When data is loaded and no errors occured, data is filled into **ListView**. But if some error occured(I have a flag in **AsyncTaskLoader** indicating that error), then **BaseAdapter** fill the first row with error message.

**Problem:**

When loading has errors, **LoaderManager** automatically tries to load data again(`forceLoad()` called), which is good. But what I need is to notify **BaseAdapter** that data is loading so **BaseAdapter** can change error message to spinning progress bar.

Is there any easy good way to notify fragment when **LoaderManager** is calling `forceLoad()`?

**My suggestion:**

ListFragment will implement the interface below and pass this ListFragment in AsyncTaskLoader's constructor.

```
public interface LoadingListener {
    public void onLoadingStatusChanged(boolean isLoading);
}
```

Then I can call `onLoadingStatusChanged(true)` in `loadInBackground()` and `onLoadingStatusChanged(false)` in `deliverResult(T data)`. I am affraid that holding reference to Fragment in AsyncTaskLoader may leak that fragment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your suggested implementation is a fine way to handle things.  Although `Loader` already presents callbacks for `OnLoadComplete` and `OnLoadCanceled`, so a started callback is the only addition you need to make.  You could also implement a custom `OnLoadStart` callback that triggers anytime `onForceLoad()` or `onStartLoad()` is called as opposed to `loadInBackground` and it would more closely mirror the existing framework callbacks.

I would suggest that, just like the framework callbacks, you set up methods to register and unregister the listener rather than passing it in the constructor, so your Fragment can attach/remove itself as part of the normal lifecycle and the reference doesn't leak.  As you mentioned, passing it in the constructor with no way to remove it would be considered a leak.

Comment: Thank you for reply. So you suggest somethink like creating methods register(Fragment f) { mFragment = f; } and unregister() { mFragment = null } in Loader and call those methods in onAttach()/onDetach() to avoid leaks?

Comment: Yeah, something like that, although I would probably make it more generic and pass in an Interface that the `Fragment` could implement.  Basically the exact same API as `OnLoadCompleteListener` and `OnLoadCanceledListener` that `Loader` already has...